# Code a plugin for the Office Communicator Client?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-2007, office-communicator

Is it possible to code a plugin for the Office Communicator Client?

I have seen code that lets me make my own client, but I want to just add functionality to the existing client.  Can that be done?

The plug-in I want to make would look for a string and if found substitute a link for it.

For example:

*Go and find Question32*

Would be changed to:

*Go and find [Question32](http://Stackoverflow.com)*

Can this kind of customization be coded into the existing client?  If so does any one have any leads on how to do it (Visual Studio C# preferred)?

EDIT: I am also willing to go with a separate app than can just monitor the incoming text.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code a plugin using the Office Communicator Automation API, but what you are requesting can't be accomplished using this API.

Your best bet here is to develop an OCS Server application using the [Office Communications Server SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632176.aspx).  This application can be written in C# and is installed on the Front End servers and intercepts traffic.  Once the traffic is intercepted, you can modify headers of the SIP messages.